# Which pronunciation and intonation is better or native-like? (two recordings of 20 seconds attached)

Tags: pronunciation, intonation

Community! Me and my sister decided to find out whose pronunciation/intonation is better. Can you please help us out?

[Recording 1 (vocaroo)](https://vocaroo.com/1lSBGMl3JiEu)

[Recording 2 (vocaroo)](https://vocaroo.com/1l6dfc4WJI3x)

Comment: Some parts are not understandable; why not provide a written transcription of what is being said?

Comment: @LPH: It's quite comprehensible. It's from *Dracula*, by Bram Stoker. Chapter 14: "Forgive me," I said. "I could not help it, but I had been thinking that it was of dear Lucy that you wished to ask, and so that you might not have time to wait, not on my account, but because I know your time must be precious, I have written it out on the typewriter for you."

Comment: @PeterShor thank you for your clarification! Also, I accidentally opened your profile, and I am wondering if you are a real author of Shor's Algorithm for integer factorization?

Comment: They both sound computer-generated to me, because of poor emphasis and rhythm.

Comment: Both of them sound like someone affecting a posh British accent for whom that is not native.

Comment: @Robusto: if you're learning English, and your teacher has a posh British accent, you're going to end up sounding like somebody affecting a posh British accent.

Comment: @PeterShor So you agree with me. ^_^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as  pronunciation goes,  from the point of view of RP standards, the recording 2 is of a somewhat better quality; the reasons are that in the first recording

1/  the vowel of "said" is a little too long  (no problem in the second),
2/ the "th" digraph is tather /t/ (pronounced correctly in the second recording)
3/ the -ing part of "thinking" is rather /in/  (the ing sound seems preserved in the second)
4/ an intrusive sound is found between "wished to" and "ask" (sounds like a t)  (no such problem in the second),
5/  the c in Lucy is pronounced z (it's pronounced right in the second recording)
6/ there is a liaison between the  words "it"  and "out" (this does not occur in the second recording, as it normally should not),

and in the second,

1/ "was" can't be made out, not because it could be reduced but because neither the sound /w/ nor /z/ can be heard (in the first recording there is no reduction but the consonants can be heard),
2/ the w in "written" seems to be appear a little (whereas in the first recording there is no "hint" of it and only an r can be made out)
3/ "for" is not reduced (it is reduced in the first recording, as normally it should).

On the count of pronunciation there is less divergence from the standard in the second recording, hence my appreciation of it as being somewhat better.

As concerns intonation, which  is more difficult to judge, there is not, in either recording, any remarkable divergence from what one might expect, no trace of an even light foreign accent. (My foreign ears can't however detect barely perceptible accents in the English language, so I can't tell whether the accent is perfectly English English or not, and that for either speaker.)
The accent could be called British English, not much different from RP.

On the whole the second speaker performs a little better.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, it must have taken a lot of time! I will continue my training of pronunciation since you brought up very good points.

Comment: @EugeneKovalev I do not believe that opinion has much to do with making the difference between for instance a /t/ and a /Ѳ/, people can find agreement among themselves for such matters; however it is this supposedly opinion based side of the question that got it closed, which is a shame as you might have had more feedback from native speakers able to pinpoint even more detail. That being said I don't think you really need training, you merely need to use your English, speak with English speaking people so as to keep up your accent (both of you).

Comment: Lots of native speakers pronounce the suffix *-ing* like *-in*. And what on earth is wrong with a liaison between the words *it* and *out*? Native speakers do this all the time. Finally, reducing *for* is always optional.

Comment: @PeterShor There is nothing wrong with a liaison and the French language is peppered with liaisons of  which even the French themselves do not know whether they are a help or a hindrance in a great number of cases nor whether to make them or not (it's a true morass for the learners), but in RP there are no liaisons and the reference I chose, because the accent is rather close to RP, is RP. Reduction in RP is well delimited by principles and not reducing strong vowels where they are traditionally reduced means a divergence from RP. This is not AmE although New England English is comparable.

Comment: @LPH: Do you have a reference for there being no liaisons in RP? That sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @PeterShor I have heard of no other type of liaison in RP than R-liaison (and intrusive r- liaison, which is not recommended); in this reference, in addition, there is the indication of a possible liaison for t (not at all) http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/langdiff/english.htm .  In the words of this  next reference liaison is a defining quality of French speech: https://www.paulmeier.com/glossary/ I'd send you the page on R-liaison that is in LPD, but the uploading from ELU and FSE chats fails repeatedly. That is all there is in this dictionary abour liaisons.

Comment: [This BBC webpage](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/pron/progs/prog1.shtml) says "When one word ends with a consonant sound and the next word begins with a vowel sound there is a smooth link between the two. In these examples the link is shown in red joining the linked words." There is absolutely nothing wrong with joining the /t/ in "it" to the word "out".

Comment: @PeterShor It sounds awful to me; it is a proof that I never heard that practice very much and that I am used to a pronunciation in words detached from one another. I added a question as regards liaisons. You'll find  in it the page I was talking about.

Comment: Listening to the recording again, I think it sounds awful to you because there's a short *pause* between the *it* and the *out*. So she's saying *written ih tout.* But if you pronounced English the way you do German, where words with an initial vowel actually are detached from each other (the way you're advocating), I think it would sound even more awful.